# React named class component vs anonymous class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a difference between a named class component and an anonymous class component? The standard pattern for HOC's is to return an anonymous class that renders the WrappedComponent. Is there any downside to exporting normal components as an anonymous class as well?

**Named class:**

MyComponent.js

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {...}

....

import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

<MyComponent />
```

**Anonymous class:**

MyComponent.js

```
export default class extends Component {...}

....

import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

<MyComponent />
```

Any implications with React Suspense?

Comment: The only immediate difference I can think of is in logging, which may or may not be handled by the name of the import--I'd check there first. One of the biggest issues w/ anonymous functions in general is the stack trace isn't immediately useful, but I haven't paid attention to how this works under ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use anonymous class component , the ones you declare implicitly or on the fly , those class components will be named as `<Unknown />` by react (React Dev tools).

E.g :

```
export default class extends Component {...}
```

will be :

```
<Unknown>
// rest of the component structure goes here
</Unknown>
```

**NOTE :**

- Unnamed class components are harder to debug
- Unnamed functions can
  cause problems with testing libraries and tools (such as Jasmine spies, Enzyme and Jest)

Comment: Not only jest but spying on unnamed components can cause problems with Jasmine and Enzyme too

Comment: So far I have just used Jest so just mentioned Jest :)

Comment: Ah okay thanks. But no performance or functional differences that you know of right?

Comment: As far as I know there is none